# Change Watchface Brightness in Android Wear

Tags: wear-os, brightness, screen-brightness, watchface

How can I change brightness of watch using Android Wear SDK (in my code) while my watch-face is running.
I want to keep brightness lower than the lowest level of Android Wear brightness settings.

Comment: Are you talking about the "active" phase of your watchface or when it is in ambient?

Comment: @AliNaddaf Actually Both :)

Comment: Have you tried the usual android approach to change the brightness?

Comment: @AliNaddaf It's lowest level is still not enough dim.

Comment: Do you mean programmatically you have set the brightness to minimum and it is still too bright?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, yes it's vivid! But it's not working in **ambient** mode on most watches:

```
private void updateBrightness() {
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
            if (!mAmbient)
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, getBrightness());
            else
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, getAmbientBrightness());
        }
```

Comment: Did you find a way to get it to work on API 26+?